# error en una funcion de editar en un proyecto de flask

Tags: json, flask

estoy haciendo una aplicacion de flask que extrae los datos de un json. en la funcion de editar me da un problema que es que no me pasa los datos correctamente de la parte que comprueba a la que edita. me pasa un objeto.
@app.route("/edit", methods = ['GET','POST'])

```
def edit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id_editar = request.form.get('id')
        if id_editar is not None:
            for usuario in data['datos']:
                if usuario.id is not None and str(usuario.id) == id_editar:
                    id_usuario = int(usuario.id)
                    print("Valor de id_editar:", id_editar)
                    print(usuario, id_usuario)
                    return render_template("edit.html", row = [usuario, id_usuario])
    return redirect(url_for('list'))
     
@app.route("/editrec", methods=['POST','GET'])
def editrec():
        global data
        print("Entrando en la función editrec")
        if request.method =="POST":
             print("Recibiendo datos del formulario")
             id = request.form['id']
             ce = request.form ['ce']
             nm = request.form ['nm']
             ap = request.form ['ap']
             psw = request.form ['psw']
             tlf = request.form ['tlf']
             ed = request.form ['ed']
             print("Datos del formulario:", request.form)  
             
             
             for row in data['datos']:
                 if str(row['id']) == id:
                     print(f"Actualizando usuario con ID {id}")
                     row['correo'] = ce
                     row['nombre'] = nm
                     row['apellidos'] = ap
                     row['contraseña'] = psw
                     row['telefono'] = tlf
                     row['edad'] = ed
             
                    
             
             with open(json_file_path,"w") as json_file:
                 json.dump(data['datos'], json_file, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, indent=2)

        return render_template('resultado.html')
```